# How to pop duplications only once from a list by comparing to another list in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, sample

I'm trying to write a card game where the cards are assigned numerical values.

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
b = [1, 2]
```

How do I remove `b` (cards you draw from a deck) from `a` to get:

```
c = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Or... How do I take a random sample away from `a` to make a separate list `b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.sample(a, n)` will give you a sample where `n` is the sample size you want:

```
>>> a = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
>>> random.sample(a, 5)
[2, 1, 3, 2, 2]
```

Alternatively you can `random.shuffle(a)` and draw `n` cards from the beginning:

```
>>> random.shuffle(a)
>>> a
[2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3]
>>> a[:5]
[2, 1, 2, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.remove()`.

> `remove()` - Remove first occurrence of value. Raises `ValueError` if the value is not present.

```
a = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
b = [1,2] 
a.remove(b[0])
a.remove(b[1])
print(a)
```

Or:

```
a = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
b = [1,2] 
for i in b:
    a.remove(i)
print(a)
```

If you want a separate list, you can create a copy of the list `a`

```
a = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
b = [1,2] 
c=a.copy()
for i in b:
    c.remove(i)
print(c)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

Deck_lst = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
Deck_lst_sequence = [i for i, v in enumerate(Deck_lst)]
Draw_cards_index = random.sample(Deck_lst_sequence, 2)
Draw_cards_value = []
for Draw_card in Draw_cards_index:
    Draw_cards_value.append(Deck_lst[Draw_card])
    Deck_lst.remove(Deck_lst[Draw_card])


print(Deck_lst)
print(Draw_cards_value)
```